# What is the difference between org.apache.http.HttpRequest and javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest?

Tags: rest, servlets, frameworks, httprequest

My research so far says that javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest is the interface to calling regular Java Servlets while org.apache.http.HttpRequest is typically used to implement RESTful services. I see an example for the same in one of the internally available frameworks in my organization where org.apache.http.HttpRequest is the interface to program RESTful services.

I still feel that org.apache.http.HttpRequest has been made available by Apache to facilitate RESTful implementation since this interface does not have any status code and works with passing entities as responses.

What exactly is the difference between the two interfaces and when one should be used over the other?

Comment: You need to provide full package names. As there is javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, I don't see any where in common packages HttpRequest, either you meant javax.servlet.ServletRequest or something from less popular 3-rd party library. Basically the difference is same as between HttpServlet and GenericServlet("Defines a generic, protocol-independent servlet"). You can read javadoc for more differences.

Answer (score 6):

HttpServletRequest is a server-side class that is part of the Java EE Servlet APIs.  You use it when you are implementing ... a servlet.

In the Java context, HttpRequest could (in theory) be anything ... because it is not a Java SE or EE class.  But usually it is a class in the Apache Http Components library.  This is *typically* used for client-side code, though it is also possible to use it server-side too.

(There are `HttpRequest` classes in non-Java contexts also ...)

---

> What exactly is the difference between the two interfaces and when one should be used over the other?

- They are unrelated interfaces. (Or "exactly" unrelated ... if you prefer :-) )
- Use `HttpServletRequest` when you are implementing servlets.
- Don't use `HttpRequest` when you are implementing servlets.

"RESTful" is orthogonal; i.e. you can implement RESTful servers using servlet, and non-RESTful servers without using servlets.

---

> I am still not clear about the basic difference between the two. Why would somebody need a `HttpRequest` in the first place if `HttpServletRequest` is already there?

Because that somebody's application may not be using the standard Java EE servlet framework.  And if they are not, then it is not "already there".

From *this* point of view, the basic difference between `HttpRequest` and `HttpServletRequest` is that they are part of different frameworks, and you use one or the other depending on which framework you are using.

---

Why do we have two classes?  Because of history.  Java EE servlets came first, and were standardized many years ago and are widely used.  The Apache HTTP Components library was implemented later to address use-cases that servlets did not address; e.g. where servlets are too heavy-weight.

- Oracle can't change Java EE to replace `HttpServletRequest` with the Apache `HttpRequest` class because it would break too much customer code.
- Apache couldn't have adopted `HttpServletRequest` in HTTP Components because it has "baggage" that is not appropriate to non-servlet use-cases.

Either way, it is what it is.

---

Which framework do you choose?  How do you choose?  Those questions are both off-topic for StackOverflow.  (Recommendations, subjective, too broad, etc)

Answer (score 0):

i think the basic difference is Httpservletrequest is part of communication between container and servlet as container creates the object for it and passes it on to servlet,while as Httprequest is part of communication between container and client  because container converts Httpservlet respone into  Httpresponse and then sends it back to client.